# WhenEvent in ParametricNDSolve with parameterized trigger fails?

Tags: differential-equations, parametric-functions, event-detection

**Edited to add**: New information at bottom.

Consider the following system of differential equations:

```
eqlist = {a'[t] == 6600 b[t] + 15000.`30. a[t] b[t] + 5.5`30.*^6 b[t]^2 + 
                   kcq b[t] c[t] + k67 b[t] c[t] - k76 a[t] d[t] + 
                   5.5`30.*^6 b[t] d[t], 
          b'[t] == -6600 b[t] - 15000.`30. a[t] b[t] - 5.5`30.*^6 b[t]^2 - 
                   kcq b[t] c[t] - k67 b[t] c[t] + k76 a[t] d[t] - 
                   5.5`30.*^6 b[t] d[t], 
          c'[t] == -k67 b[t] c[t] + 85 d[t] + kcq a[t] d[t] + 
                   k76 a[t] d[t] + 5.5`30.*^6 b[t] d[t] + 30000 c[t] d[t] + 
                   5.5`30.*^6 d[t]^2, 
          d'[t] == k67 b[t] c[t] - 85 d[t] - kcq a[t] d[t] - k76 a[t] d[t] - 
                   5.5`30.*^6 b[t] d[t] - 30000 c[t] d[t] - 
                   5.5`30.*^6 d[t]^2, 
          A60[t] == (19879 b[t])/200, 
          A70[t] == (1073 d[t])/200, 
          Atot[t] == A60[t] + A70[t], 
          a[0] == 1/125, 
          b[0] == 0, 
          c[0] == 11/500, 
          d[0] == 0, 
          A60[0] == (19879 b[0])/200, 
          A70[0] == (1073 d[0])/200, 
          Atot[0] == A60[0] + A70[0]};
impulse1 = WhenEvent[t == 10^-4, {a[t] -> -((893 Ilaser)/(1000 125)) + a[t], 
                                  b[t] -> (893 Ilaser)/(1000 125) + b[t], 
                                  c[t] -> -((2021 Ilaser 11)/(250 500)) + c[t], 
                                  d[t] -> (2021 Ilaser 11)/(250 500) + d[t]}];
result1 = ParametricNDSolve[Append[eqlist, impulse1], {a, b, c, d, A60, A70, Atot}, 
                            {t, 0, 0.002}, {kcq, k67, k76, Ilaser}, 
                            WorkingPrecision -> 30];
Plot[Evaluate[((# /. result1)[30000, 5 10^6, 5 10^6, 5 10^-3][t]) & /@ {A60, A70, Atot}], 
     {t, 0, 0.002}, PlotRange -> Full, Frame -> True, ImageSize -> Large]
```

[image]

Which works as it should. But if I try to parameterize the time offset, it fails:

```
impulse2 = WhenEvent[t == t0, {a[t] -> -((893 Ilaser)/(1000 125)) + a[t], 
                               b[t] -> (893 Ilaser)/(1000 125) + b[t], 
                               c[t] -> -((2021 Ilaser 11)/(250 500)) + c[t], 
                               d[t] -> (2021 Ilaser 11)/(250 500) + d[t]}];
result2 = ParametricNDSolve[Append[eqlist, impulse2], {a, b, c, d, A60, A70, Atot}, 
                            {t, 0, 0.002}, {kcq, k67, k76, Ilaser, t0}, 
                            WorkingPrecision -> 30];
Plot[Evaluate[((# /. result2)[30000, 5 10^6, 5 10^6, 5 10^-6, 0.1 10^-3][t]) & /@ 
              {A60, A70, Atot}], {t, 0, 0.002}, PlotRange -> Full, Frame -> True, 
              ImageSize -> Large]
```

[image]

Is this behavior expected? Is there a workaround?

**New information:** If we evaluate the functions to plot, we get an interesting clue:

```
Evaluate[((# /. result1)[30000, 5 10^6, 5 10^6, 5 10^-3][t]) & /@ 
         {A60, A70, Atot}]
```

[image]

```
Evaluate[((# /. result2)[30000, 5 10^6, 5 10^6, 5 10^-6, 10^-4][
 t]) & /@ {A60, A70, Atot}]
```

[image]

Why are the domains so small in the second case?

Comment: Put `t0=10^-4` and look

Comment: I'm not following. If I replace the 0.1 10^-3 with 10^-4, I get the same problem I showed above.

Comment: OK! See my answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Adding

```
"LocationMethod" -> "LinearInterpolation"
```

to the `WhenEvent` specification fixes the problem. It is not clear to me why the original formulation doesn't work, however.

Answer (score 1):

Not an answer to the original question, but rather a detailed response to @AlexTrounev's answer...

First, some "experimental" data to fit to:

```
sample[t_] = (0.002 + 101 t - 461000 t^2 + 2.218 10^9 t^3 - 3.64 10^12 t^4 + 
              3.17 10^15 t^5) Exp[-8653 t];
data = SetPrecision[Table[{t, sample[t] + 
                          RandomVariate[NormalDistribution[0, 0.00001]]}, 
                          {t, 0, 0.002, 0.000004}], 30];
```

Next setting up the system of equations in a series of variables so that it can be used identically in both approaches:

```
rateeqs = {a'[t] == k1b b[t] + ksqb b[t] a[t] + kttb b[t]^2 + 
                    kbd b[t] c[t] - kdb a[t] d[t], 
           b'[t] == -k1b b[t] - ksqb b[t] a[t] - kttb b[t]^2 - 
                    kbd b[t] c[t] + kdb a[t] d[t], 
           c'[t] == k1d d[t] + ksqd d[t] c[t] + kttd d[t]^2 + 
                    kdb a[t] d[t] - kbd b[t] c[t], 
           d'[t] == -k1d d[t] - ksqd d[t] c[t] - kttd d[t]^2 - 
                    kdb a[t] d[t] + kbd b[t] c[t]};
initconc = {a[0] == a0, b[0] == b0, c[0] == c0, d[0] == d0};
additionaltdeps = {abs60[t] == 5 eps60 b[t], abs70[t] == 5 eps70 d[t],
                   abs[t] == abs60[t] + abs70[t]};
additionalinitcond = {abs60[0] == 5 eps60 b[0], abs70[0] == 5 eps70 d[0], 
                      abs[0] == abs60[0] + abs70[0]};
tdepvars = {a, b, c, d, abs60, abs70, abs};
fixedparams = {k1b -> 6000, k1d -> 100, ksqb -> 10^6, ksqd -> 10^6, 
               kttb -> 10^9, kttd -> 10^9, a0 -> 4 10^-5, c0 -> 2 10^-5, 
               eps60 -> 3500, eps70 -> 12000};
varparams = {kbd, kdb, b0, d0};
initguesses = {kbd -> 5 10^8, kdb -> 10^8, b0 -> 10^-7, d0 -> 10^-8};
```

My approach:

```
solution = ParametricNDSolve[SetPrecision[Join[rateeqs, initconc, additionaltdeps, 
                                               additionalinitcond] /. fixedparams, 30], 
                             tdepvars, {t, 0, 0.002}, varparams, 
                             WorkingPrecision -> 30];
```

Alex's approach:

```
model[kbdval_?NumberQ, kdbval_?NumberQ, b0val_?NumberQ, d0val_?NumberQ] := 
 Module[{}, First[abs /. 
   NDSolve[SetPrecision[(Join[rateeqs, initconc, additionaltdeps, additionalinitcond] /.
                        fixedparams) /. 
                        MapThread[(varparams[[#1]] -> #2) &, 
                          {Range[4], {kbdval, kdbval, b0val, d0val}}], 30], 
           tdepvars, {t, 0, 0.002}, WorkingPrecision -> 30]]]
```

Initialize the list of current values:

```
tmp = varparams /. initguesses;
```

Look at the two models with the same parameters and subtract them from each other to ensure they give the same results:

```
Column[{Row[{"tmp = ", tmp}], "", 
  Grid[{{"My Model", "Your Model", "Comparison"}, 
        {Show[ListPlot[data, ImageSize -> Automatic -> 400, 
                       ImagePadding -> {{50, 1}, {1, 1}}, Frame -> True], 
              Plot[(mymodel = ((abs /. solution) @@ tmp))[time], 
                   {time, 0, 0.002}, PlotStyle -> Red, PlotRange -> Full]], 
         Show[ListPlot[data, ImageSize -> Automatic -> 400, 
                       ImagePadding -> {{50, 1}, {1, 1}}, Frame -> True], 
              Plot[(yourmodel = (model @@ tmp))[time], {time, 0, 0.002}, 
                   PlotStyle -> Red, PlotRange -> Full]], 
         Plot[mymodel[time] - yourmodel[time], {time, 0, 0.002}, 
              ImageSize -> Automatic -> 400, Frame -> True, 
              PlotRange -> Full]}, 
        {ListPlot[{#1, #2 - mymodel[#1]} & @@@ data, ImageSize -> Automatic -> 400, 
                  ImagePadding -> {{50, 1}, {50, 1}}, Frame -> True, AspectRatio -> 0.2], 
         ListPlot[{#1, #2 - yourmodel[#1]} & @@@ data, ImageSize -> Automatic -> 400, 
                  ImagePadding -> {{50, 1}, {50, 1}}, Frame -> True, AspectRatio -> 0.2], ""}}]}]
```

[image]

And the two models give the same results. Now, setting up a dynamic plot (using my model, since it is faster) to monitor the fit progress:

```
Column[{Row[{"tmp = ", Dynamic@N[tmp, 5]}], 
        Dynamic@Show[ListPlot[data, ImageSize -> Automatic -> 400, 
                       ImagePadding -> {{50, 1}, {1, 1}}, Frame -> True], 
                     Plot[((abs /. solution) @@ tmp)[time], {time, 0, 0.002}, 
                       PlotStyle -> Red, PlotRange -> Full]], 
        Dynamic@ListPlot[{#1, #2 - ((abs /. solution) @@ tmp)[#1]} & @@@ data, 
                         ImageSize -> Automatic -> 400, 
                         ImagePadding -> {{50, 1}, {50, 1}}, Frame -> True, 
                         AspectRatio -> 0.2]}]
```

I will show the animation of this for my version in a moment.

Doing the fit using my approach:

```
myresult = AbsoluteTiming[
  NonlinearModelFit[data, ((abs /. solution) @@ varparams)[t], 
                    Evaluate[{#, # /. initguesses} & /@ varparams], t, 
                    Method -> "LevenbergMarquardt", 
                    StepMonitor :> (tmp = varparams), 
                    Gradient -> "FiniteDifference", WorkingPrecision -> 30]]
tmp = Values[myresult[[2]]["BestFitParameters"]]
```

[image]

I get the answer back in 14.8005 seconds.

Reset the parameters to the same starting point:

```
tmp = varparams /. initguesses;
```

Doing the fit using Alex's approach:

```
yourresult = AbsoluteTiming[
  NonlinearModelFit[data, (model @@ varparams)[t], 
                    Evaluate[{#, # /. initguesses} & /@ varparams], t, 
                    Method -> "LevenbergMarquardt", 
                    StepMonitor :> (tmp = varparams), 
                    Gradient -> "FiniteDifference", WorkingPrecision -> 30]]
```

The fit progresses as observed by the dynamically-updated plot (my earlier comment that it wanders off and stalls was because I had forgotten to add `WorkingPrecision`->30 to your approach), but I aborted it after about 45 minutes, at which point it still needed several more iterations before getting a fit of the same quality as my approach did.

So the upshot is that the `Module` encapsulated `NDSolve` is far, far slower than `ParametricNDSolve` when used in `NonlinearModelFit`.

Comment: I can’t understand what you are trying to do. If your code with 1 works, why use a second code? My code is different there, and here you use it incorrectly.

Comment: It's a different model that doesn't have a `WhenEvent` so both `Module`/`NDSolve` works and `ParametricNDSolve` works. This shows the orders-of-magnitude speed difference for the same problem. Since`ParametricNDSolve` does a lot of the calculation up front, and doesn't redo that calculation upon changing parameters, it is immensely faster than `Module`/`NDSolve`, which *does* have to restart from scratch at every change of parameters (e.g., parameter optimization). Having shown that, I hope you can see why I need a `ParametricNDSolve` approach that can handle parameterizing a `WhenEvent`.

Comment: You expressed disdain that I would combine `NonlinearModelFit` with `ParametricNDSolve`, despite that it works in many situations (every case I have tried other than `WhenEvents`) and it is used in examples elsewhere (https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/125814/simultaneous-fitting-of-parametricndsolve-with-varying-initial-conditions,  and dozens more, as well as published articles in peer-reviewed journals). So I apologize if I am coming across as difficult, but telling me that I am mistaken or that I used your code incorrectly without pointing me to HOW I am wrong isn't helpful.

Answer (score 0):

We remove `t0` from among the parameters of `ParametricNDSolve[]`, then we obtain

```
eqlist = {a'[t] == 
   6600 b[t] + 15000.`30. a[t] b[t] + 5.5`30.*^6 b[t]^2 + 
    kcq b[t] c[t] + k67 b[t] c[t] - k76 a[t] d[t] + 
    5.5`30.*^6 b[t] d[t], 
  b'[t] == -6600 b[t] - 15000.`30. a[t] b[t] - 5.5`30.*^6 b[t]^2 - 
    kcq b[t] c[t] - k67 b[t] c[t] + k76 a[t] d[t] - 
    5.5`30.*^6 b[t] d[t], 
  c'[t] == -k67 b[t] c[t] + 85 d[t] + kcq a[t] d[t] + k76 a[t] d[t] + 
    5.5`30.*^6 b[t] d[t] + 30000 c[t] d[t] + 5.5`30.*^6 d[t]^2, 
  d'[t] == k67 b[t] c[t] - 85 d[t] - kcq a[t] d[t] - k76 a[t] d[t] - 
    5.5`30.*^6 b[t] d[t] - 30000 c[t] d[t] - 5.5`30.*^6 d[t]^2, 
  A60[t] == (19879 b[t])/200, A70[t] == (1073 d[t])/200, 
  Atot[t] == A60[t] + A70[t], a[0] == 1/125, b[0] == 0, 
  c[0] == 11/500, d[0] == 0, A60[0] == (19879 b[0])/200, 
  A70[0] == (1073 d[0])/200, Atot[0] == A60[0] + A70[0]}; t0 = 10^-4;
impulse2 = 
  WhenEvent[
   t == t0, {a[t] -> -((893 Ilaser)/(1000 125)) + a[t], 
    b[t] -> (893 Ilaser)/(1000 125) + b[t], 
    c[t] -> -((2021 Ilaser 11)/(250 500)) + c[t], 
    d[t] -> (2021 Ilaser 11)/(250 500) + d[t]}];
result2 = 
  ParametricNDSolve[
   Append[eqlist, impulse2], {a, b, c, d, A60, A70, Atot}, {t, 0, 
    0.002}, {kcq, k67, k76, Ilaser}, WorkingPrecision -> 30];
Plot[Evaluate[((# /. result2)[30000, 5 10^6, 5 10^6, 5 10^-6][
      t]) & /@ {A60, A70, Atot}], {t, 0, 0.002}, PlotRange -> Full, 
 Frame -> True, ImageSize -> Large]
```

[image: Figure 1]

For use with `NonlinearModelFit[]`, I recommend the code

```
model[kcq_?NumberQ, k67_?NumberQ, k76_?NumberQ, Ilaser_?NumberQ, 
   t0_?NumberQ] :=  
  Module[{A60, t}, 
   First[A60 /. 
     NDSolve[{a'[t] == 
        6600 b[t] + 15000.`30. a[t] b[t] + 5.5`30.*^6 b[t]^2 + 
         kcq b[t] c[t] + k67 b[t] c[t] - k76 a[t] d[t] + 
         5.5`30.*^6 b[t] d[t], 
       b'[t] == -6600 b[t] - 15000.`30. a[t] b[t] - 
         5.5`30.*^6 b[t]^2 - kcq b[t] c[t] - k67 b[t] c[t] + 
         k76 a[t] d[t] - 5.5`30.*^6 b[t] d[t], 
       c'[t] == -k67 b[t] c[t] + 85 d[t] + kcq a[t] d[t] + 
         k76 a[t] d[t] + 5.5`30.*^6 b[t] d[t] + 30000 c[t] d[t] + 
         5.5`30.*^6 d[t]^2, 
       d'[t] == 
        k67 b[t] c[t] - 85 d[t] - kcq a[t] d[t] - k76 a[t] d[t] - 
         5.5`30.*^6 b[t] d[t] - 30000 c[t] d[t] - 5.5`30.*^6 d[t]^2, 
       A60[t] == (19879 b[t])/200, A70[t] == (1073 d[t])/200, 
       Atot[t] == A60[t] + A70[t], a[0] == 1/125, b[0] == 0, 
       c[0] == 11/500, d[0] == 0, A60[0] == (19879 b[0])/200, 
       A70[0] == (1073 d[0])/200, Atot[0] == A60[0] + A70[0], 
       WhenEvent[
        t == t0, {a[t] -> -((893 Ilaser)/(1000 125)) + a[t], 
         b[t] -> (893 Ilaser)/(1000 125) + b[t], 
         c[t] -> -((2021 Ilaser 11)/(250 500)) + c[t], 
         d[t] -> (2021 Ilaser 11)/(250 500) + d[t]}]}, {a, b, c, d, 
       A60, A70, Atot}, {t, 0, 0.002}]]];
Plot[model[30000, 5 10^6, 5 10^6, 5 10^-6, 10^-4][t], {t, 0, 0.002}, 
 PlotRange -> All, Frame -> True, ImageSize -> Large]
```

[image: Figure 2]

Comment: But the entire point is to have t0 as a parameter of ParametricNDSolve! That way it can be optimized as compared to experimental data using NonlinearModelFit.

Comment: Who uses `ParametricNDSolve` with `NonlinearModelFit`? Use `Module` instead of  `ParametricNDSolve`.

Comment: Context here: https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/203849/problem-combining-parametricndsolve-with-nonlinearmodelfit/203865 (I don’t understand how Module could replace ParametricNDSolve)

Comment: See update to my answer (code with `Module`).

Comment: So I did a comparison of your approach (`Module` with `NDSolve` followed by `NonlinearModelFit`) to mine (`ParametricNDSolve` followed by `NonlinearModelFit`) using a different model system that does not have the `WhenEvent` bit so that both approaches work, and checked the timing of the fit step with `AbsoluteTiming`. My approach took 12.0938 seconds and got me to the right answer. Yours took 288.086 seconds and stalled at a horrible fit.

Comment: You may have been mistaken.

Comment: If so, I welcome the correction. Please see my added answer.